# ESP8266 only executes Sketch after switching on/off CH_PD pin

Tags: esp8266, arduino-ide, wifi, sketch, wires

I started a new project with an ESP8266-01 module. I want to use it as stand-alone circuit to send an Email at the press of a button.

The wiring is:

- VCC    -  3.3v VCC
- CH_PD  -  3.3v VCC
- GND    -  GND
- GPIO_2 -  Push down button (internal pullup)

I've the sketch (Arduino IDE), I've upload it and it essentially works. However:

- If I call the `sendEmail();` method inside the `void setup(){}`, it works like a charm.
- If I add an push down button on Pin #2 (GPIO_2) it only works if I previously have removed VCC from the CH_PD pin and reattached it again shortly after.

Now, I would bet I read something regarding (or similar) this situation a couple of days back, but I am unable to find it again, now that I need it.

Is there a solution for this or am I missing something?

Any help will be greatly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The GPIO0 and GPIO2 determine what mode the module starts up. GPIO0 and GPIO2 need to have pull-up resistors connected to ensure the module starts up correctly. You can also use RX pin for the button.

Comment: Thanks @AltAir for your response. I've followed step #4 of this instructable http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-the-ESP8266-01-pins/   but still doesn't work as I needed it to...

Comment: You can try a bulk capacitor between VCC and GND close to the module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after literally spending hours trying to figure out what the heck is going on, I decided to test the setup with a ESP8266-12 NodeMcu, which is essentially the same but more resembling to an Arduino in that it has more in/out pins and it's better for testing.

On this platform I got a different behavior. I was able to send an Email by the push of the button but... only once. So apparently, contrary to what I believed, something was wrong with the code.

In the code there is this method, which essentially initiates the WiFi connection:

```
void initializeWifi(){

  WiFi.begin(WIFI, PASSWORD);

  // allow time to make connection
 while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)  delay(5000);

  }
```

Somehow the `delay(5000);` didn't seem right as delay usually freezes the whole thing. When I commented out the line, everything worked as expected. With the NodeMcu as well as with the ESP8266-01.

However, I still have to figure out how to give time to the WiFi to connect without freezing out all together. Probably it's the time for `millis()`;

I hope this becomes useful to somebody else in the future.